# Solving for general matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to solve for the matrix $X$ given the following equation:

$$
AXB + CX + XD + E = 0
$$

where $A, B, C, D, E$ are all matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the equation to be consistent, the matrices must have the following sizes:
$$\eqalign{
m,n &= {\rm size}(X) = {\rm size}(E) \\
m,m &= {\rm size}(A) = {\rm size}(C) \\
n,n &= {\rm size}(B) = {\rm size}(D) \\
}$$
Using Kronecker $(\otimes)$ products, we can [transformed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the given equation into a vector equation which can be solved with standard techniques.
$$\eqalign{
&\Big((B^T\otimes A) + (I_n\otimes C) + (D^T\otimes I_m)\Big){\rm vec}(X)
 + {\rm vec}(E) = 0 \\
&{\rm vec}(X) = -\Big((B^T\otimes A) + (I_n\otimes C) + (D^T\otimes I_m)\Big)^{-1}{\rm vec}(E) \\
&X = {\rm Reshape}\Big({\rm vec}(X),\,m,\,n\Big) \\
}$$
where $I_n$ denotes the $(n\times n)$ identity matrix.

If the indicated matrix inverse does not exist, then there is no solution.
However, the pseudoinverse can be used to obtain the best *least-squares* solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic algebra. You can't do matrix division but you can multiply by the inverse of a matrix to to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrices are $n \times n$, this can be considered as an $n^2 \times n^2$ linear system in the entries of $X$.  Of course if $n$ is large, this might not be very efficient.